# Cross-compiling Rust project fails due to missing libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, rust, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile a Rust project from x86-64 to armv7 (Raspberry Pi 3B+). That project uses the [`cxx`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx) for some of its functionality.
I set up the [toolchain](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-toolchain-bin/), installed the `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` target with `rustup`, and after some trial and error, I copied the required header files to `/usr/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/include`. I also copied the `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` directory from a live Raspbian to `/usr/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib`.
Then I executed `cargo build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`. That gives me the following error: https://pastebin.com/2LVZnQMQ.
I then made sure that `libc.so.6` is in `/usr/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib` and `libc_nonshared.a` is in `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`. That did not solve the issue.

I am lost as to what more the linker wants. What else do I need to copy to successfully compare the binary?

Comment: Can you get pure Rust hello world to cross-compile successfully? Can you get a pure C++ hello world to cross-compile successfully?

Comment: I was sure it worked before. It again complains about not having `libc`. I assume that I'll have to install [arm-linux-gnueabihf-glibc](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/arm-linux-gnueabihf-glibc/), yes?

Comment: Probably. If that doesn't work, which failed: the C++, the Rust, or both?

Comment: Both fail with the same error message. So far, trying to install glibc has proven to be a very difficult task. I'll come back if I figure anything out

Comment: It might be worth filing an issue with Rust because `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` is a tier 2 target and thus should build.